# Angular Promise with condition

Tags: angular, promise, es6-promise

I don't want to hit the endpoint (`getUserInfo`) if I already have value in my variable, I wrote a code like below but there is duplicate code and wanted to see if anyone has a better way of writing this:

```
let report;
if (this.userInfo) {
   report = {
    ReportType: reportType,
    ReportID: id,
    ReportFormat: format,
    ReportName: `${reportType}_${id}`,
    Filters: shouldNotParseFilters ? filterContent : [],
    ViewFields: columns || [],
    OrgName: this.userInfo[0].orgname,
    FullName: this.userInfo[0].fullname
  } as SavedReport;
  if (!shouldNotParseFilters) this.reportFilterService.mapReportFilters(<ReportFilterContext>filterContent, report);
  report.Filters.push({ 'maxitems': [-1] });
  this.nrcService.downloadReport(report, fileName).subscribe({ error: err => this.nrcService.handleError(err) });
}
else {
  this.nrcService.getUserInfo().then(data => {
    this.userInfo = data;
     report = {
      ReportType: reportType,
      ReportID: id,
      ReportFormat: format,
      ReportName: `${reportType}_${id}`,
      Filters: shouldNotParseFilters ? filterContent : [],
      ViewFields: columns || [],
      OrgName: data[0].orgname,
      FullName: data[0].fullname
    } as SavedReport;
    if (!shouldNotParseFilters) this.reportFilterService.mapReportFilters(<ReportFilterContext>filterContent, report);
    report.Filters.push({ 'maxitems': [-1] });
    this.nrcService.downloadReport(report, fileName).subscribe({ error: err => this.nrcService.handleError(err) });
  })
 }
```

Comment: In the body of the if/else, simply create a promise, then call .then on it after the conditional, thus removing the duplication.

Comment: I'm just learning angular, and not sure what you mean, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would suggest to use `async/await` to solve your needs:

```
// Add `async` here 
async your_function_name () {
    ...
    let report;
    if (!this.userInfo) {
        // Waits until your user info is loaded
        this.userInfo = await this.nrcService.getUserInfo();
    }
    report = {
        ReportType: reportType,
        ReportID: id,
        ReportFormat: format,
        ReportName: `${reportType}_${id}`,
        Filters: shouldNotParseFilters ? filterContent : [],
        ViewFields: columns || [],
        OrgName: this.userInfo[0].orgname,
        FullName: this.userInfo[0].fullname
    } as SavedReport;

    if (!shouldNotParseFilters) {
        this.reportFilterService.mapReportFilters(<ReportFilterContext>filterContent, report);
    }

    report.Filters.push({ 'maxitems': [-1] });
    this.nrcService.downloadReport(report, fileName).subscribe({ error: err => this.nrcService.handleError(err) });

}
```

If you're not familiar with `async/await` see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ;-)

Another option is to use Promises without `async/await`, but it does not look so nice:

```
let report;
// Create a new promise, which resolves directly
let promise = new Promise(r => r());
if (!this.userInfo) {
    // Assigns the loading promise to the promise variable
     promise = this.nrcService.getUserInfo().then(data => {
        this.userInfo = data;
    });
}
// Waits until the promise is resolved
promise.then(() => {
    report = {
        ReportType: reportType,
        ReportID: id,
        ReportFormat: format,
        ReportName: `${reportType}_${id}`,
        Filters: shouldNotParseFilters ? filterContent : [],
        ViewFields: columns || [],
        OrgName: this.userInfo[0].orgname,
        FullName: this.userInfo[0].fullname
    } as SavedReport;

    if (!shouldNotParseFilters) {
        this.reportFilterService.mapReportFilters(<ReportFilterContext>filterContent, report);
    }

    report.Filters.push({ 'maxitems': [-1] });
    this.nrcService.downloadReport(report, fileName).subscribe({ error: err => this.nrcService.handleError(err) });

});
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, it worked, btw I'm not downvoting these answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use async/await, something like

```
this.userInfo = await this.userInfo || this.nrcService.getUserInfo();
report = { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm not sure who is downvoting but I just voted you back up, somebody did that to me too, not sure because of I'm too familiar with JS, not fair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async method() {
    const userInfo = await this.nrcService.getUserInfo();
    if (!!userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = userInfo;
    }
    if (!!this.userInfo) {
        report = {
            ReportType: reportType,
            ReportID: id,
            ReportFormat: format,
            ReportName: `${reportType}_${id}`,
            Filters: shouldNotParseFilters ? filterContent : [],
            ViewFields: columns || [],
            OrgName: this.userInfo[0].orgname,
            FullName: this.userInfo[0].fullname
        } as SavedReport;

        if (!shouldNotParseFilters) {
            this.reportFilterService.mapReportFilters(<ReportFilterContext>filterContent, report);
        }

        report.Filters.push({ 'maxitems': [-1] });
        this.nrcService.downloadReport(report, fileName).subscribe({ error: err => this.nrcService.handleError(err) });
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```